How to Read Base64 Encoded Messages from an Existing RabbitMQ Queue Using MassTransit?
I am using the following code and the MassTransit library to connect to a pre-existing RabbitMQ queue and read from it. I want to read the data written in this queue, which is a string encoded in Base64 format. How can I achieve this?
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("test-queue", e =>
    {
        e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
        e.ClearMessageDeserializers();
        e.UseRawJsonSerializer();
        e.Consumer<TestQueueConsumer>(context);
        e.Durable = true;
        
        //e.Consumer<TestQueueConsumer>();
        //e.Bind("test-queue", x =>
        //{
        //    x.Durable = true;
        //    x.AutoDelete = false;
        //    x.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Fanout;
        //    //x.RoutingKey = "notifications.info";
        //});
    });

    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

I wrote this message to the queue: test message. However, when I retrieve the message, I get the following error:

